# Can I use both GCM and FCM in my app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android project in which GCM is implemented. Back-end (server) is already coded suitably with GCM.

Now is it possible to add firebase (FCM) in my project and work in parallel with GCM? I cant migrate to FCM because it is impossible to change my back-end code as it is a big project and too much code is there. Has anyone done something like this?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is strictly recommended to use FCM instead of GCM. FCM is way more easier than GCM. and moreover google may stop giving support to GCM now or any sooner so better go with FCM.

Comment: you should try to migrate your data. refer this https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: but if I do so then I may have to change my back-end.. there may be loads of reference (i am not sure).. so I am not confident enough to migrate

Comment: but if in future google stops support and then you will end up no where..so better start now

Comment: do I have to change every reference in my backend? it is something related location and broadcast receivers constantly check broadcast intents..

Comment: nope.nothing big it is..the request params you send are same but the services link changes. and API key changes. other than this. FCM provides easiest way to handle token registering and unregistering unlike GCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not use both FCM and GCM at same time. GCM is the old version and that it is strongly recommended to use FCM.

> **Why is Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) part of Firebase? How does it relate to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?**
>
> Google is investing in Firebase, making it our unified mobile
>   platform.
>
> Over the last few years, we have expanded GCM to send messages to
>   multiple platforms beyond Android: iOS and Chrome. Firebase is known
>   for being cross platform, so FCM now makes a natural fit in the
>   Firebase suite of features designed for Android, iOS, and mobile web.
>
> Another core value of Firebase is cross-feature integration. We are
>   adding the ability for other Firebase features to easily send messages
>   via FCM. For example, you can use Firebase Notifications to send
>   reengagement messages to your users.
>
> We think that GCM will be even more useful to developers as an
>   integrated part of Firebase. You can still get the same great product,
>   now under a new name: "Firebase Cloud Messaging," or FCM for short.
>
> **Is GCM going to be deprecated?**
>
> We will continue to support the current version of GCM Android and iOS
>   SDKs because we know a lot of developers are using GCM SDKs today to
>   handle notifications, and client app upgrade takes time.
>
> But all new client-side features will be added to FCM SDKs only moving
>   forward. You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to FCM SDKs.

You can get more details [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)

Comment: I don't think this answers the concern. Question was whether it is possible to support both at the same time, not what is recommended.
So I presume it is still open and possible that both can be used within an Android app until GCM is faded completely - then FCM would remain as the only one cloud messaging library.

Answer (score 6):

Though my particular case might be a bit specific, because the project I am involved in has a very specific backend, it seems to me FCM interoperates well with GCM, i.e you can have both in your app, GCM and FCM broadcast receivers / receiver services, and they will both work as well with no conflicts.

This has a huge advantage because you don't have to decide with migration at once, you can do this more gradually.

Well done, Google!

Answer (score 0):

As per [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) you don't need additional server configuration when you're migrating your client app from GCM to FCM, so just use FCM in your android app.

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) the docs on how to migrate your app

Comment: I added my project to my firebase console. The GCM is set up with another developer. So different sender ID, different tokens ; what change I need to make in my back-end?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem to use both GCM and FCM together. You will get to different `deviceToken` and one of these token get `NotRegistered` error.

For my FCM token always get `NotRegistered` error but the app is active and not **uninstalled** and my GCM token is valid and gets a push notification.