# Google/CloudMessaging' and Firebase/Messaging' fail with erro duplicate symbol

Tags: xcode, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am using Firebase in my project as well as Google sing-in. 
For that I am using pod library.

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

This are my pod which I am using in project.

Now I am remove `pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'` then app build successfully but `GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)`
 giving error like below

You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project directory.

If I am adding `pod "Google/CloudMessaging` pod and then build project XCode fail with `duplicate symbols`.

How can I add two and also avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cant use GCM and FCM at the same time as FCM is the new improved GCM and you're certainly going to run into those kind of errors. You can see that question addressed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841945/can-i-use-both-gcm-and-fcm-in-my-app)